# WKWebView doesn't navigate on window.location change

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview

In a `WKWebView`, I load a webpage with a `window.location = newURL` JS inside. The newURL is never reached. `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` delegate is never even called (while the `window.location` change is correctly called in JS)

I can't change the JS part (not my site at all), only the `WKWebView` side. Any idea of what I can do to make my view navigate to new URL ?

Comment: I had to do this for a project I'm working on and it works fine. The callback `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` definitely gets called. Did you make sure you assigned the `wkwebview.navigationDelegate` ??

Comment: @Tumata it's not being called on iOS 9. On the other hand iOS 10+ works fine